# How to find a specific row in an index

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and am not very familiar with it. I am supposed to find a name that starts with b in index, which i do not have the slightest clue of doing.

```
| id | name         | DoB        | class | marks | dept_id |
+----+--------------+------------+-------+-------+---------+
|  1 | Data Science | 2006-07-15 |    11 |   100 |       3 |
|  2 | Garry        | 2006-08-20 |    11 |    92 |       4 |
|  3 | Jane         | 2006-03-22 |    10 |    95 |       2 |
|  4 | Benny        | 2005-10-10 |    12 |    74 |       4 |
|  5 | Karen        | 2005-01-15 |    12 |    88 |       3 |
|  6 | Camy         | 2006-04-18 |    12 |    91 |       2 |
|  7 | Farhan       | 2006-09-21 |    11 |    80 |    NULL |
|  8 | Shamil       | 2005-10-19 |    11 |    90 |       3 |
+----+--------------+------------+-------+-------+---------+
```

The Table above is (students)
And the one Below it is the Index of (students)

```
+----------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+----------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| students |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | id          | A         |           6 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| students |          1 | dept_id    |            1 | dept_id     | A         |           3 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| students |          1 | name_index |            1 | name        | A         |           6 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| students |          1 | index_name |            1 | name        | A         |           6 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+----------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Does `select * from students where name like 'b%'` not work?

Comment: Does case sensitivity matter I wonder

Comment: For clarity please add your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `SELECT` query with `LIKE` keyword

- The `percentage ( % )` wildcard matches any string of zero or more characters. For example, `b%` matches any string starts with the character `b` such as `Benny` and `Ben`.

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE name LIKE 'b%';
```

If you have same `name` in record which starts from uppercase as well as lowecase then put `BINARY` keyword after `LIKE` keyword (Case Sensitive):

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE name LIKE BINARY 'b%';
```

Comment: Does case sensitivity matter I wonder

Comment: @P.Salmon It's worked either name starts with `b` or `B`

Comment: But what if op only wants lower case b?

Comment: You have to put `BINARY` keyword after `LIKE` keyword

Comment: Thank you for the clarification but what I was supposed to do what do all that but in index

Comment: @Dare I don't understand what you want to do? Tell clearly please.